# Nilpotency class of a nilpotent group.

Tags: group-theory

From Macdonald's The Theory of Groups, 1968:

Theorem 9.02. All subgroups and factor groups of the nilpotent group G  are nilpotent. If G is of class r then every subgroup and factor group has class r.

The definition the author uses for nilpotency class is the following: Definition 1: A group with a central series of length r is said to be nilpotent of class r. I perfectly understand the proof of the theorem assumming definition 1.  But let's replace by definition 2: Definition 2:  the class of G is the least length any central series of G can have. Now it's impossible for me to prove the theorem. Is the statement used in  theorem 9.02 true assuming definition 2?

Comment: Definition 1 is wrong. An alternative correct definition is that the nilpotency class is the length of the lower central series of $G$. Or alternatively, you could define it to be the length of the upper central series.

Comment: @DerekHolt Given the theorem, it seems like the author meant class at most $r$, rather than class $r$ (as otherwise the theorem is of course false).

Comment: Yes, that is the definition of the author. That is, he defines the class as being the length of any central series for G, and so, his definition is of class less than or equal to r really.